# esp8266 and cp2102 don't work with python serial

Tags: python, serial-port, esp8266

esp8266 and cp2102 don't work! Why?

```
import serial

sp="/dev/ttyUSB0"

port = serial.Serial(sp)

while True:
    port.write("AT+RST")
    rcv = port.read(10)
    print rcv
```

I pressed "AT+RST"[Enter] and don't have "READY" after it.

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: Did you test it with a Serial console before?
Mine is running 115200 baud. Firmware: 00150900
Try to send it from a console (non software serial) with 3.3 volt

Comment: yes. console work fine without esp8266 and with tx-rx autoself connected

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include CRLF (\r\n) characters at the end of your command.  I lost a day messing with this before I figured that out.  I got the local echo back of the command but since I never sent a \r\n I would not get any more data.  Here is what works for me as a basic terminal in Python using pyserial:

```html
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A8004xaO', 115200, timeout=2.5)
while True:
    cmd = raw_input("> ");
    ser.write(cmd + "\r\n")
    ret = ser.read(len(cmd)) # eat echo
    time.sleep( 0.2 )
    while ( ser.inWaiting() ):
        ret = ser.readline().rstrip()
        print ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting a baud rate when opening the serial port. The default is probably not appropriate for the ESP8266.

Comment: I modify code, but it dont work:`code` port = serial.Serial(
        port = sp,\
        baudrate=9600,\
        #parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
        #stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        #bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=5000
)`code`

Comment: The ESP8266 uses 115200 baud by default, not 9600.

Comment: are you sure? not worked with 115200, see http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/WiFi_Serial_Transceiver_Module